# Why is the following if statement not working in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm implementing a double `if` statement under the `BeforeSave` Sub in Excel VBA but it is not working. I have a checkbox in my excel sheet that outputs `TRUE` or `FALSE` in `F11` when it is checked or unchecked, respectively. Also, if all the cells I want filled in the sheet are filled the cell `A1` will change from "" to "   ".

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

If Sheet2.Range("F11").Value = "TRUE" Then
If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Sheet requires input(s). All cells must be filled."
Cancel = True
End If
End If

End Sub
```

The output expected is that excel will not let me save if the first If Statement is true and the second If is blank, but the actual output is that it lets me save no matter what. Also, it should let me save if the first If is False regardless of the second if output.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56581983/edit) to include more information.

Comment: `If Sheet2.Range("F11").Value Then`

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the second if-statement (`If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "" Then`) to check if the outer if-statement ever evaluates to true? (The code pauses when it hits a breakpoint. So if the code never pauses on a breakpoint on the second if-statement, than the first if-statement is always failing.)

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible reasons:

- You are referring to two different sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2), is this correct?
- Instead of using `Value = ""`, you might want to use the `IsBlank()` worksheet function.

Comment: Will the `IsBlank()` return true when the `""` is a result of a function? That was how I read the situation from the last sentence above the code.

Comment: `IsBlank()` gives TRUE or FALSE as output, which might be used as input for the IF-clause.

Comment: But as @Mistella stated if the return of the null string is due to a formula like `=IF(1<>1,0,"")` then ISBLANK will return FALSE.

Comment: Yes, i am referring to two different sheets on purpose and VBA says the IsBlank function: method not found